# How to get first/shorter match with regex in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

In ruby:

```
"experience"[/.e/] 
=> "pe"
```

Just like expected. However...

```
"experience"[/.*e/] 
=> "experience"
```

Is there a way to write a regular expression that returns to first/shorter version it comes across?

```
"experience"[regexp]
=> "expe"
```

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. I had read that article and tried [.*?e], which wasn't what I was looking for.

The answer is

    [.+?e]

Comment: A better way of writing the regex might be the variant that also works in [possessive form](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html). This means being more specific in what you want to match. `/([^e]|\Ae)++e/` matches at least one character that is not an `e`, but also allows the `e` if it is at the start of the string. It keeps matching until an `e` is encountered and then matches that by having a trailing `e` in the regex. `"experience"[/([^e]|\Ae)++e/] #=> "expe"`

Comment: [Here is the demo](http://rubular.com/r/5mBQxGdNGQ). I had to wrap it in an extra pair of parentheses since Rubular only shows the resulting groups.